# android - how to play a mp3 file from file manager in my music player?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a music player app in android studio. When I run it, there is no issue and the app is running well but when I try to play a song from file manager, the app selection popup shows my app. When I select my music player, it opens music player but not playing the song. only shows the last played song. How can I automatically play the selected song? Is there any intent I need to capture?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    sMainActivity = this;
    action = getIntent().getAction();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    navigationMap.put(Constants.NAVIGATE_LIBRARY, navigateLibrary);
    navigationMap.put(Constants.NAVIGATE_PLAYLIST, navigatePlaylist);
    navigationMap.put(Constants.NAVIGATE_QUEUE, navigateQueue);
    navigationMap.put(Constants.NAVIGATE_NOWPLAYING, navigateNowplaying);
    navigationMap.put(Constants.NAVIGATE_ALBUM, navigateAlbum);
    navigationMap.put(Constants.NAVIGATE_ARTIST, navigateArtist);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    panelLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    View header = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header);

    albumart = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.album_art);
    songtitle = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
    songartist = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);

    setPanelSlideListeners(panelLayout);

    navDrawerRunnable.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
            setupNavigationIcons(navigationView);
        }
    }, 700);


    if (RamUtils.isMarshmallow()) {
        checkPermissionAndThenLoad();
    } else {
        loadEverything();
    }

    addBackstackListener();
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code ?

Comment: @Ben_Gratvol Kindly check the code

Answer (score 0):

> How can I automatically play the selected song?

If your app is showing up in the chooser, you must have the proper `<intent-filter>` set up.

Then, all you need to do is call `getIntent().getData()` from `onCreate()` (and possibly `onNewIntent()`, depending upon how you are handling tasks in your manifest). That will give you the `Uri` to the content, one that will match the specifications you put in the `<data>` elements in your `<intent-filter>`. You can then play back that content using your existing music-playing logic.